# Pandas : problems when converting .txt to .csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, txt

I am trying to use tables in pandas.

The original data look like that (.txt file):

µm            nm
1.34E+00    1.39E+00
1.34E+00    1.61E+00
...

When I manually convert the file from .txt to .csv, by opening it in excel and saving as a .csv file, I obtain something like that:

µm;nm
1.339216;1.388997
1.340324;1.612847
1.341462;1.587352
1.342533;1.686544
...

Which is working fine in pandas, using the following code:

```
file =('filename.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep = ";")
df
```

[dataframe from manually obtained .csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQylw.png)

Which is what I want. But since I am planning to deal with a lot of those files, I need to process them as batch. So I need to obtain the same dataframe from the original files, which come as .txt.

But if I try to do that from the original data, it looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVgI2.png)

The code is as follows:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', sep = ";", encoding = 'unicode_escape')
df2.to_csv('filename-2.csv', sep='\t', index=None)
df2
```

Please note that I use the 'unicode_escape' value to avoid the error message "utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: invalid start byte"

I tried to specify various separators, but without success so far.

I hope someone will be able to help.

Thanks,

Sébastien.

Comment: While read `df2`, have you tried giving separator as \t?

Comment: Post your code as text in the question itself. Images can't be copied, tested, executed or googled. CSV *is* text. It's a text file with fields separated by commas. Python strings are Unicode so there's no reason to escape or unescape anything.

Comment: You'll have to check what separator is used in the file you want and specify it in `read_csv`. CSV is just a text file with separators. If the file uses a different separator you can still use `read_csv` by specifying the correct separator. `;` isn't a comma for example. It's commonly used in half of the world which uses `,` as a decimal separator

Comment: There is something happening when I open the .txt file in file and save it as .csv that I cannot reproduce with pandas...

The .txt file looks like this:
   µm          nm
1.34E+00 1.39E+00
1.34E+00 1.61E+00
1.34E+00 1.59E+00
1.34E+00 1.69E+00

After conversion into .csv through excel, I obtain this:
    µm          nm
1.339216 1.388997
1.340324 1.612847
1.341462 1.587352
1.342533 1.686544
1.343659 1.910365
1.344734 1.660482
1.345845 1.585136
1.346938 1.634419
1.348139  1.908091

Comment: The problem is that pandas won't opn my .txt file unless I specify something regarding the Unicode. Otherwise, I have the error message "utf-8' codec can't decode..."

Answer (score 0):

While read df2, you should use the same separater as the one given while writing it (assuming it is written from `df`.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', sep = ';')
```

Or if .txt is a separate file altogether,

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', sep = '\t')
```

This should give correctly formatted dataframe.